# Onto function with domain of rational numbers and co-domain of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, rational-numbers

I'm trying to find an onto function $f: \mathbb{Q} \to\mathbb{N}$

I'm somewhere along the lines of $f(q) = |(1 - q)| + q$ for non integers, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: How about $f(a/b)=|a|+1$?

Comment: You have to be careful here.  It is easy to construct a function that is not well defined.  Consider, a function is well-defined if, for $x_1 = x_2$ then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  So take for instance $1/2 = 2/4 \in \Bbb Q$.  Then for $f(a/b) = |a|$ we would have $f(1/2) = 1 \neq f(2/4)=2$

Comment: Is your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ 0-inclusive?

Comment: no, it is not 0 inclusive

Comment: To expand on the previous comment, you can more simply define $f(\frac mn) = m + 1$ where $\frac mn$ is fully reduced and $m$ is non-negative; every rational can be expressed as such.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding how that function is onto. Is there a way you could graph the function so I may see it visually?

Comment: If we fix $n$ such that it is equal to $1$ ($m \geq 0$), it is clearly onto(can you see why?). If we let $n$ vary, it remains onto but ceases to be one-to-one.

Comment: I've been studying way too long.. totally mixed up the definitions of onto and 1-1 functions. Totally makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35952/discussion-between-shan-solo-and-mathematicsstudent1122).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the users commenting on the question, I understand the problem. $f$($m$/$n$)=|$m$|+1 is an onto function, as long as $m$/$n$ is in reduced form.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical example to show that the rationals are countable and that defines a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N}$:

[image]

You proceed taking $f(1/1)=0$ and then enumerate the fractions you encounter on the path described by the arrows, skipping the ones you have already considered previously.

Comment: Just curious, is there an explicit formula for this bijection?

Comment: Seriously doubt it, it's too hard to consider in a single formula the fact that you have to skip equivalent fractions

Comment: Hmm. The reason I'm asking is because a "pictorial" proof isn't satisfying (as far as rigour goes...)

Comment: There is actually, I have seen it.  It's an algorithm that counts each fraction exactly once.  I'll try and track it down.

Comment: I'd be very curious if you find it!

Comment: 0

down vote
 
https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/recounting.pdf

Check out this paper by Neil Calkin

Comment: What does 0 down vote means? Yes the paper explains a recursive way to find f but still doesn't give an explicit formula as asked. It's enteresting nonetheless

Comment: It means I accidentally posted that as an Answer, then copy/pasted it as a comment, but didn't see it grabbed more than I meant...